# Dynamically populate an object's attributes in Ruby, whose attribute names are the same as hash keys

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash:

```
row = {:id => 1, :name => "Altus Raizen", :email => "altus@blarg.com"}
```

Now I have a `Person` Struct with the same attributes as the keys in `row`:

```
Person = Struct.new(:id, :name, :email)
```

I want to dynamically populate a `Person` object using the values in the `row` hash as follows:

```
person = Person.new
person.id = row[:id]
person.name = row[:name]
person.email = row[:email]
```

The code above works, but there must be a more elegant way of doing this, i.e. populating the attributes dynamically. How do I do this?  (I have 9 attributes actually, so the code above become much longer and "uglier" by considering to set values to the other attributes such as phone, address, etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
person = Person.new
row.each_pair { |key, value| person.send("#{key}=", value) }
```

Answer (score 2):

In ruby >= 1.9. you can do:

```
row = {:id => 1, :name => "Altus Raizen", :email => "altus@blarg.com"}
Person = Struct.new(:id, :name, :email)

p person = Person.new(*row.values)
# => <struct Person id=1, name="Altus Raizen", email="altus@blarg.com">
```

Which happens to work because everything is in the right order. More control gives `values_at`, which also works on older Rubies:

```
row = {:id => 1, :name => "Altus Raizen", :email => "altus@blarg.com"}
Person = Struct.new(:id, :name, :email)
p person = Person.new(*row.values_at(:id, :name, :email))
```

Another option is OpenStruct:

```
require 'ostruct'
row = {:id => 1, :name => "Altus Raizen", :email => "altus@blarg.com"}
person = OpenStruct.new(row)
p person  #=><OpenStruct id=1, name="Altus Raizen", email="altus@blarg.com">
puts person.name #=> Altus Raizen
```

Comment: which editor you  used to run or play with code? asked from curiosity.